# How to display image using php from a database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Newbie here.
Im having a hard time diplaying the images to my homepage, using the my code below, it would only show like a white empty outline of the image. I didn't directly store the pictures on the database because from what I have heard, it's a bad practice. Can someone help me and correct the codes I have written.

My database is composed of

- DB name: pamphotos
- table name: photos
- rows : username, p_src,p_desc,p_thumbsrc, p_id

Here's an actual content of my db row:

- username: a
- p_src : C://wamp//www//PAM//uploads//890021-1360x768-[DesktopNexus.com].jpg
- p_desc: lemur
- p_thumbsrc: C://wamp//www//PAM//uploads//thmb//890021-1360x768-[DesktopNexus.com].jpg
- p_id: 16

And this is my code.

```
<?php

    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pamphotos") or die('error in connection'.mysqli_connect_error());
    $q = "SELECT * from photos WHERE '$user'=username ";

    $stmt = mysqli_query($con, $q);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))
        {
            echo "<img src='".$row['p_src']."' width='175' height='200' />";
        }
?>
```

Comment: PHP and HTML work differently in terms of directories. PHP looks at it from the server side so c:\wamp\www is correct, but not in HTML. In HTML you link to an image like http://mydomain.com/image.png.

Comment: Is the file location in or below your web server root directory, and readable to the web server?

Comment: @JAL Thanks for the reply. My folder for the images are inside the www folder.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have deleted that post due to that fact that the question was unclear and confusing.

Comment: You ought to edit that post to make it clearer instead of deleting and posting again. Have some modesty and respect.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Apologies. I'll keep that in mind. Once again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
username: a
p_src : C://wamp//www//PAM//uploads//890021-1360x768-[DesktopNexus.com].jpg
p_desc: lemur
p_thumbsrc: C://wamp//www//PAM//uploads//thmb//890021-1360x768-[DesktopNexus.com].jpg
p_id: 16
```

you should have in your database:

```
username: a
p_src : /PAM//uploads//890021-1360x768-[DesktopNexus.com].jpg
p_desc: lemur
p_thumbsrc: /PAM//uploads//thmb//890021-1360x768-[DesktopNexus.com].jpg
p_id: 16
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried changing it. It successfully uploads the photo location but it gives an error.
Here's the error: Warning: move_uploaded_file(//PAM//uploads//1376472_10202181335281075_198154253_n.jpg) [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\PAM\PAM-upload.php on line 90